# Reading Files via readFilesContents()

Tags: java

There's a trivial game I'm trying to make, so I want to read a file (txt format) to post information about the game in a console for a player. I used this method to read file:

```
List<String> readFileContents(String path) { 
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(Path.of(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
```

It works, but when I choose the option to print? I've got something like this:

```
[text, some other text, more text]
```

But I want it to be printed like this:

```
text
some other text
more text
```

What should I do?

Comment: your code is showing what you return to something, but not the part printing it. how are you parsing through the `List<String>` which is returned?

Comment: `public void printHowToPlay() {
        System.out.println(readFileContents("resources/Document.txt"));
    } `

Comment: If the printing of the strings is not happening as expected, then it is quite pointless to be showing us how you do the reading of the strings. Show us how you do the printing of the strings instead. Duh!

Comment: @Chernosmaga please [edit] your question and add information to it. don't provide extra info in comments/answers

Answer (score 1):

Just showing the result of the print is pointless without showing how you print it. But assuming the result you got, I might say it's what you get when you print a variable of type `List<E>` with `System.out.println()`, which just prints the list like this: `[element1, element2, element3, ...]`. To get every element on its own line, you have to loop over the list.
You can use a standard for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Or a for-each loop:

```
list.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v));
```

Or a method reference:

```
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

These options will give you the expected result. Hope that helps.